# Why can't I install tidymodels in jupyter notebook?

Tags: r

```r
install.packages(tidymodels)
library(tidymodels)
```

I installed tidymodels package in Jupyter notebook, however, I can not use this library.
What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it needs an updated version of the `recipes` package.  You need to update the package; running `install.packages("recipes")` may do the trick.